# making a fix when workin in git branch

Tags: git, branch

I would like to check out if there is a better workflow for this. Suppose, I am just working in a feature branch and did already some commits there when I discover a flaw in the master code. Lets assume, there is just a little typo somewhere I wanna fix. Then I would have to this to make it clean:

```
# I am now in feature branch 
git stash              # save current work
git checkout master
git checkout -b fix    # ok, making a fixbranch could be passed
# fix the flaw
git commit
git checkout master
git rebase/merge fix   # whatever you prefer
git checkout feature
git stash apply
git rebase master
# now the flaw is fixed in my feature branch and in master and I can go on working
```

Thats really a lot of steps. Alternatively I could of course fix the flaw in the feature branch, but then it would remain unfixed in the master until I merge the branch. And when I even don't know, if I ever will merge the branch, it could stay unfixed.

But is there any better/less uncomplicted way to manage this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the correct workflow.

Suppose you are many developers to work on same repo. Others dev would like to get benefits of your quick fix. Dedicated quickfix branch and merge on master is a clear way to do that.

If your team delevery process is simple (ex. no need of review before merging on master) you could commit your fix directly on master without creating dedicated fix branch. simple but could embed some risk...

Suppose now your are the only one developer. Then just have to make a  dedicated commit for the quick fix on your feature branch. that's it.

---

nb: you could avoid using the `git stash` feature by committing first your ongoing work then use `git commit --amend` when you go back to yor branch